# Layout blocks inside blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, xml

I'm trying to add captcha to custom form and i'm currently struggling with layouts here.

```
<reference name="content">
      <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="meistras.wrap" as="meistras-wrap"    translate="label">
           <block type="formailer/form" name="meistroforma" as="meistroforma" unique_id="e3t3aWRnZXQgdHlwZT0iZm9ybWFpbGVyL2Zvcm0ifX0-" template="asd/formailer/widget/form_template.phtml">
               <block type="studioforty9_recaptcha/explicit" name="studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit" template="studioforty9/recaptcha/explicit.phtml"/>
           </block>
      </block>
</reference>
```

When i try to call studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit block inside form_template.phtml file:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit');
```

I get nothing. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your _type_ declaration doesn't gel with the _name_ declaration. If the _name_ declaration is correct, try `type="studioforty9/recaptcha_explicit"`

Comment: please provide your config.xml code

Comment: Is the **asd** part correct in:  `template="asd/formailer/widget/form_template.phtml"`?

Comment: Type declaration is correct. And the **asd** is also correct. But still doesn't work.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first understand the following blocks: `core/template`, `core/text_list`, `core/text`.  The point is to find out which ones will render on their own, and which ones require an explicit call to render them.

Next, you should look up the block `page/html_wrapper` and see what actions are available.

```
<block type="page/html_wrapper" ...> 
    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
</block>
```

So, if you want to skip looking up the purpose of core blocks, then just try adding `output="toHtml"` to the blocks to see if that helps.  For example (adding to both blocks like below will help you debug, but will probably show more output than you are expecting, so try individually):

```
<block type="formailer/form" name="meistroforma" as="meistroforma" unique_id="e3t3aWRnZXQgdHlwZT0iZm9ybWFpbGVyL2Zvcm0ifX0-" template="asd/formailer/widget/form_template.phtml" output="toHtml">
       <block type="studioforty9_recaptcha/explicit" name="studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit" template="studioforty9/recaptcha/explicit.phtml" output="toHtml" />
```

---

**Hint**

If you examine the *`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`* the block-type for the block named **content** is `core/text_list`... Here's is the source:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setText('');
    foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $name) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($name);
        if (!$block) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block: %s', $name));
        }
        $this->addText($block->toHtml());
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

The snippet above is gathering the rendered block html of each of the children for output.  Meaning, the `core/text_list` doesn't need an explicit `toHtml` output call.

**Summary of my point**

You have your `<reference name="content">`, therefore it's children will render the html.  But the children's children, perhaps require a little more help with rendering output html.

Here are some good functions to play around with for debugging:

```
Zend_Debug::dump();
echo $this->getChildChildHtml();
echo $this->getChildHtml();
echo $this->getParentBlock()->getBlockHtml();
echo $this->getParentBlock()->getBlockAlias()
```

---

**Try this:**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="meistras.wrap" as="meistras-wrap" translate="label">
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>meistras-container</value></action>
        <block type="formailer/form" name="meistroforma" as="meistroforma" unique_id="e3t3aWRnZXQgdHlwZT0iZm9ybWFpbGVyL2Zvcm0ifX0-" template="asd/formailer/widget/form_template.phtml" output="toHtml">
           <block type="studioforty9_recaptcha/explicit" name="studioforty9.recaptcha.explicit" template="studioforty9/recaptcha/explicit.phtml"/>
       </block>
  </block>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!. But still doesn't show up.. This is very strange in my opinion. Maybe there is another way here? Maybe replacing page/html_wrapper with something else?